# Exit_status=15 , what does it mean?

Tags: hpc, pbs

I have a job which stops unexpectedly with Exit_status=15. What is the most probable error ?

Comment: You tagged your question as using PBS, then see [here](http://www.eresearchsa.edu.au/pbs_exitcodes).

Comment: Tarek, welcome to SciComp! We tend to discourage and delete questions that can be answered with a simple Google search using the terms in the question; I'm guessing fcruz did so when he commented. Could you elaborate on what you think the problem might be?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @fcruz, that is a SIGTERM.  i.e the kernel asked your program to stop for some reason.
   SIGTERM can come for a whole lot of reasons.  Have you tried instrumenting your code to see where you are at when the error crops up?  I most often get that when I blow my memory ceiling.